# Python subprocess can't find the output of csv writer

Tags: python, bash, csv, subprocess, gzip

I'm ripping some data from Mongo, sanitizing it via Python, and writing it to text file to import to Vertica. Vertica can't parse the python-written gzip (no idea why), so I'm trying to write the data to a csv and use bash to gzip the file instead.

```
csv_filename = '/home/deploy/tablecopy/{0}.csv'.format(vertica_table)

with open(csv_filename, 'wb') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for replacement in mongo_object.find():
        replacement_id = clean_value(replacement, "_id")
        csv_writer.writerow([replacement_id, booking_id, style, added_ts])

subprocess.call(['gzip', 'file', csv_filename])
```

When I run this code, I get "gzip: file: No such file or directory," despite the fact that 1) the file is getting created immediately beforehand and 2) there's already a copy of the csv in the directory prior to the run, since this is a script that gets run repeatedly.

These points make me think that python is tying up the file somehow and bash can't see/access it. Any ideas on how to get this conversion to run?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the `csv_filename`, gzip is looking for a file called  `"file"` which does not exists so it errors not the `csv_filename` file:

```
subprocess.call(['gzip',  csv_filename])
```

There is no `file` argument for gzip, you simply need to pass the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got the correct answer to your problem.... but alternately, you can use the `gzip` module to compress as you write so there is no need to call the `gzip` program at all. This example assumes you use python 3.x and you just have `ascii` text.

```
import gzip

csv_filename = '/home/deploy/tablecopy/{0}.csv'.format(vertica_table)

with gzip.open(csv_filename + '.gz', 'wt', encoding='ascii', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for replacement in mongo_object.find():
        replacement_id = clean_value(replacement, "_id")
        csv_writer.writerow([replacement_id, booking_id, style, added_ts])
```

Comment: when I used the gzip module vertica couldn't read the data from the file. that's a separate problem that probably merits its own question